# NHibernate Cache Trouble

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm

I have two entities having one to many relation and these are User and Address. One user can have many addresses. I am using one session and transaction per HTTP request pattern and Level 1 cache is turned on. For some reason I am seeing that my lazy loaded collections are not taking care of changes made to the data. For example If I create one user object. Then I create two address objects and save them like

```
User u1 = CreateNewUser("olduser@xyz.tld", "olduser@xyz.tld");
u1.Save();

Address a1 = CreateNewAddress(u1, "olduser@xyz.tld", "Old1", "User1");
a1.Save();
Address a2 = CreateNewAddress(u1, "olduser@xyz.tld", "Old1", "User1");
a2.Save();
Session.Flush();
Assert.AreEqual(2, u1.Addresses.Count); // THIS IS FAILING BECAUSE COUNT IS 0
```

Now when doing assert I am expecting user object to lazy load two address and count should be 2 but it returns 0. If I simply throw away complete cache by doing Session.Clear() call that doesn't work either. But if I throw away complete cache by doing Session.Clear() and then load my user object again this way it works as expected. I am not sure am I missing something or there is still something missing in NHibernate cache set-up configurations. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add the addresses to the user class too...   Typically you see people creating a method u1.AddAddress(a1); which will set the reference to the user on the address object and add it to the address list in the user.

Comment: Well I am new to NHibernate but I think this is suppose to be done by NHibernate. I think within same session NHibernate keeps track of all changes and notifies the related items. Isn't that the case.

Comment: Well... I assume your User class has a List of addresses.   You will need to add to that list if you want the Count() to be 2.  NH will not do this for you until you reload the objects from the DB again.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the addresses to the user object or refresh the user object (reload it from the database):

```
Session.Flush();
Session.Refresh(u1);
Assert.AreEqual(2, u1.Addresses.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Default transaction type here is read committed, so you need a Flush() after each Save() or change the transaction type.